# Naming anti-electrons and anti-protons

Tags: soft-question, terminology, antimatter

I think I understand why an anti-electron is called a positron (since it symbolizes positive charge)

But why then is anti-proton called an anti-proton and not a [negatron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negatron)?

Comment: You are looking for logical explanations where none exist!

Comment: For ... Historical Reasons (tm).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [asking for the reasons for notation and terminology is off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/50583).

Comment: I disagree with the close vote because I once wasted an entire day trying to track down just what a "negatron" was in a 1950s-ish paper.

Comment: @rob: while I may empathize with wasting a day on terminology, that doesn't change the fact that asking for reasons for notation/terminology is explicitly off-topic on the site, as given in the link ACuriousMind gave.

Comment: Note that [hsm.se] accepts some naming questions. Don't know how they'd feel about this one, but if you want it migrated just say.

Comment: Also note that in ACuriousMind's meta link, the answer "such questions are on-topic" currently as more votes than the accepted answer "it depends."

Comment: I think that we'd close this on HSM, because the question could be asked in many ways, like "Why isn't an antiproton called a non-a-proton?", or "Why isn't an antiproton called an opposite-to-a-proton?" If you were going to ask "Why is the prefix -anti used to denote antimatter?", then the question is less broad . . . and easily answered on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter#History_of_the_concept) ("The term antimatter was first used by Arthur Schuster . . ."). This would not be a good fit for HSM.

Comment: @rob: looks even to me (but votes come in when it's linked). Anyways, the *accepted* answer is policy, not the others.

Answer (score 2):

After the discovery of the positron in the early 1930s there was a suggestion in the particle physics community to use the name "negatron" to refer to the negatively-charged constituent of ordinary matter, so that the matter-antimatter pair would be negatron/positron.  However it never really caught on among chemists and biologists and people who don't deal with antimatter.

Here's some data I got a while back from [Google's ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=positron%2C+negatron%2C+electron&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpositron%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnegatron%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectron%3B%2Cc0#) showing the number of books published each year using the words "electron", "positron", "negatron."  You can see a big jump in the positron numbers after the particle was discovered; negatron never really took off.

[image: ![ngram data]

Given this history, it would be deathly confusing to repurpose "negatron" for the antiproton.  The longer word is unambiguous.